# Bootstrap and AJAX Issue: submit doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form:

```
<form class="dark-bg iq-pall-30" action="" id="mainform" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Here is my "submit-button":

```
<a href="#" class="button" onclick="$('#mainform').submit();">Go</a>
```

That's working well. But when I try to use ajax it doesn't.

```
  $('#mainform').submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "link..",
            data: $("#mainform").serialize(),
            success: function(json){
                if (json['error']) {
                    $("#content22").html(json['result']);
                }
                if (json['result'])
                {
                    $( "#mainsec" ).empty();       
                    $("#content22").html(json['result']);          
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

As a result, I got an empty page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what mean by result here you can show error by assigning a element id to .html(#element-id) to show what error there is.

Comment: It's not important 'cause it doesn't work with this code:
success: function(json) { alert('ajax');}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This Way :

```
<form class="dark-bg iq-pall-30" action="" id="mainform" method="post">


</form>

<a href="#" type="button" class="button" onclick="submitForm();">Go</a>

   <script>
    function submitForm(){    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "link..",
            data: $("#mainform").serialize(),
            success: function(json){
                if (json['error']) {
                    $("#content22").html(json['result']);
                }
                if (json['result'])
                {
                    $( "#mainsec" ).empty();       
                    $("#content22").html(json['result']);          
                }
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Are there any way with a href onclick?

Comment: Sometimes data from form ($("#mainform").serialize()) is incorect. Like it use previous data. Why it can be so? Thanks.

Comment: use `$("#mainform")[0].reset();` . on success of ajax , it will reset form after once submitted .